# Automate connection from one linux system to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I have two linux systems, namely m1 and m2. I want to connect to m2 using m1. For this, I am executing the following command from m1:

```
ssh m2
```

In addition, after getting connected to m2, I want to execute certain commands in the m2 system. Finally, I would like to fetch the output of these commands.

For example:

1. After getting connected to m2.
2. I will run few commands in m2, like ls, grep etc.
3. I will also execute the shell script written on m1 in m2.
4. Finally, I would like the output of these commands executed in m2 to be available in m1.

My goal is to automate this set of steps. Please, note that I am not allowed to install any softwares on either of the machines because of the security issues. That's why I cannot use `Python + Paramiko` to achieve the aforementioned goal.

However, I have looked into `expect` and `autoexpect` command. But still I am not sure how to go ahead with the task.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not that specific in your request, you're not mentioning HOW that connection is to get initiated, whether the commands on m2 will need input, but here's a basic approach ...

```
scp shellscript m2:.
ssh m2 "command1; command2; ..." | ./local_process_on_m1
```

Comment: @JohnRambo : amended process ... still don't see a need for expect =}

Comment: I just came across "expect" while I was searching for the aforementioned problem.